# A program to control media on a remote computer

Tags: media-player

I took an old computer and connected it to my stereo.

Currently I use RDP to play the music but it is slow an annoying to have to login every time I want to change a track.

What I am looking for is a program that can run on the old computer and show me my music library via a browser or a client on my PC and allow me to play the music on the remote PC connected to the stereo.

I found lots of media server apps that can play back on my computer but I want the playback on the remote machine.

FYI: the specs of my system are Pentium 4, Windows XP Pro

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use, for example, WinAMP + [Winamp Web Interface plugin](http://www.winamp.com/plugin/winamp-web-interface/92511), or you can use [AjaxAMP](http://ajaxamp.com/download)

Comment: They are both good. AjaxAmp is a bit heavier but a lot newer and feature rich. Thanks!

Comment: You are wellcome

Answer (score 0):

Those are great answers if you would like to stick to Windows XP as your platform, however; if you should find yourself feeling adventurous try this...

1. install ubuntu server, http://www.ubuntu.com/download/server
2. get cmus,

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install cmus

its commandline player for music there are many types of CLI players cmus is just what works for me.
3. get ssh if you don't have it...
sudo apt-get install ssh

now you can ssh into the machine and play any file it can access locally.  If you really want to get fancy realize that you can mount remote (windows or linux) file systems, drives, usb sticks, whatever onto your linux server which now can be controlled remotely to play music.

My home setup is essentially this... linux server + sound card + speakers and it can play music from any filesystem in my home.

To make it even sweeter!!!!! if you love www.pandora.com

see:

http://kevinmehall.net/p/pithos/

you can add the ubuntu repo and sudo apt-get pithos... which is a GUI client for pandora, the cool thing here is it also installs pianobar.

pianobar is a command-line client for pandora... so yes, you guessed it, you can load it on ubuntu and play your pandora account through your headless, ssh managed linux music server.

Slick, easy, and fast.

Just a thought :-)